# Editor group notch in visual studio code editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way (setting) - we can add notch between editior group (file tabs) in visual studio code like sublime

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Nope. There is no setting.

> UI developer, HTML5, CSS3, Web Graphic Design,

You can probably try to use this extension: [Custom CSS and JS loader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css)

And write some CSS that would emulate sublime tabs. Similar to:

```css
.tabs-container > .tab {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
    transform: translateZ(0) perspective(1px) skewX(30deg);
}
.tabs-container > .tab > * {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
    transform: translateZ(0) perspective(1px) skewX(-30deg) !important;
}
```

[image: tabs-demo]

Comment: Thanks @Alex I will try this for sure

Answer (score 0):

@Alex - Thank you for your suggestion,

```
.tabs-container {
    margin-top: 5px;
    background: #252526;
}

.tabs-container > .tab {
    background: transparent!important;
    border-bottom-width: 40px!important;
    border-bottom-style: solid!important;
    border-bottom-color: #42433e;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent!important;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent!important;
    position: relative;
}

.tabs-container > .tab:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: -10px;
}

.tabs-container > .tab.active {
    border-bottom-color: #1e1e1e;
    z-index: 9;
}

.tabs-container > .tab > * {
  padding-bottom: 10px;  
}
```

[image]